# Laravel Form Request several validation rules of same type

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation, laravel-form

I have a Form Request Validation file, which checks is an input field not empty `('required')` and then if it's value exists in the database in table `'table1'`.

I want to add a 2nd exist rule to the same input field, and return a message if 2nd exist validation rule is not met:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'tour' => 'required|exists:table1,id|//another exists: table2, id//'
        ];
    }

        public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'tour.required' => 'Message 1!',
            'tour.exists:table1,id' => 'Message 2!',
            'tour.//another exists: table2, id//' => 'Message 3!'
        ];
}
```

Right now only 2nd rule works. Any ideas how-to?:)

thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation you can write your custom validation rule. For example, let create a class called CustomValidator (place him in folder like 'App\Services' or another that you want).

CustomValidator.php

```
namespace App\Services;

class CustomValidator {
    public function myexistsValidate($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($parameters); $i += 2) {
            $count = \DB::table($parameters[$i])->where($parameters[$i + 1], $value)->count();
            if (!$count) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

We created a new rule called `myexists`. This rule can accept pair of paramaters divided by commas lile this: 'myexists:table1,searchfield1,table2,searchfield2...'`
I wrote very simple example of implementation of this rule, ofc you can add some approach or another validations...

Next you must register your own validation rule in AppServiceProvider in method `boot` (string that you place as a first parameter will be a name of new rule):

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use \Validator;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Validator::extend('myexists', 'App\Services\CustomValidator@myexistsValidate');
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Next in your FormRequest place code like this:

```
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [
        'id' => 'myexists:tableName1,field1,tableName2,field2',
    ];
    return $rules;
}
```

You can add a validation message for this rule, for example in your `lang\en\validation.php` file `'myexists' => 'Field :attribute must exists in all described tables.'`

Comment: :) maybe you can help me with this also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44886845/laravel-form-request-array-validation-custom-rules